# Creating facebook share video button for videos on my website

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, youtube-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have a local language website in which i am fetching videos from youtube using youtube API.

http://www.chanderraj.com

Now, i want if any user watching video on my site and want to share that video on his facebook wall, he/she can share video by clicking a button below video. Like youtube give us option to embed, share video below every video.

I have tried using facebook share plugin by appending video id in querystring like

http://www.chanderraj.com/index.aspx?v=09u_34jfjd where 09u_34jfjd is youtube video id, but it is not fetching any video thumbnail.

then i tried simply posting http://www.chanderraj.com in my fb status but is also does not have any video thumbnail. So what changes i have to do in my website to show videothumbnail at least using http://www.chanderraj.com/index.aspx?v=09u_34jfjd url which is having video id also.

Or, i have to use facebook API.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/

Comment: "09u_34jfjd" is not a videoId, since (until now) it is always 11 characters in length. This videoId string is 10 characters.

Comment: @user1067083 but that will not create thumbnail when i will share